# How to UnitTest Custom MediaTypeFormatter

Tags: c#

```
public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream stream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        //go lookup the concrete for the interface
        var newType = GetNewType(type);
        var newValue = GetNewValue(value, type);

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(newType);
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream, _encoder))
            {
                var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                ns.Add("", "");
                serializer.Serialize(streamWriter, newValue, ns);
            }
        });
    }
```

This Custom mediatypeformatter is trying to serialize the the namespaces of the xml. Im trying to test this method but throws an error with Cannot access a closed Stream. Is there a way to unit test this method.

Comment: How are you generating the input stream?

Comment: im trying to test it with HttpClient.PostAsync("http://test/api/test" object, new customformatter());   if that you meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an abstraction of the serializer

```
public interface ISerializer
{
    void Serialize(StreamWriter writer, object value, XmlSerializerNamespaces ns);
}
```

Then inject an `ISerializer` to your implementation of `MediaTypeFormatter` by using constructor injection (thanks to @pep for pointing out). This enables you to pass a dummy implementation.

```
public class MyMediaTypeFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{
    private ISerializer _serializer;
    public MyMediaTypeFormatter(ISerializer serializer)
    {
        _serializer = serializer;
    }
    ...
}
```

`WriteToStreamAsync` then simply uses `_serializer`:

```
public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream stream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
{
    var newType = GetNewType(type);
    var newValue = GetNewValue(value, type);
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream, _encoder)) {
            var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("", "");
            _serializer.Serialize(streamWriter, newValue, ns);
        }
    });
}
```

A possible implementation:

```
public class MyXmlSerializer<T> : ISerializer
{
    private readonly XmlSerializer _xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    public void Serialize(StreamWriter writer, object value, XmlSerializerNamespaces ns)
    {
        _xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, ns);
    }
}
```

Possible dummy:

```
public class DummySerializer : ISerializer
{
    // You can test these properties in the unit test after the call;
    public StreamWriter Writer { get; private set; }
    public object Value { get; private set; }
    public XmlSerializerNamespaces NS { get; private set; }
    public int Calls { get; private set; }

    public void Serialize(StreamWriter writer, object value, XmlSerializerNamespaces ns)
    {
        Writer = writer;
        Value = value;
        NS = ns;
        Calls++;
    }
}
```

Or use NSubstitute or another mocking framework. Note: these frameworks automatically create dummy implementations of interfaces at runtime.

Programming against interfaces instead of concrete classes not only adds flexibility to your code, but is often mandatory for unit testing.

Comment: Thanks Olivier, im using MS unit test and kinda lost here. but you give me some inspiration.

Comment: One issue with this answer is that you can't change the signature of the `WriteToStreamAsync` method, since it belongs to `System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatter`. Aside from the fact that you'll need to find another way to inject the `ISerializer`, this answer is on the right track. You probably need to inject an instance of `ISerializer` via a constructor injection into your implementation of the abstract `MediaTypeFormatter`.

Comment: @pep: Yes constructor injection is a great thing. IoC containers can inject them automatically. I use [DryIoc](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc) which is a great tool. But whether you use constructor or method injection depends on the whole context.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try opening the stream first and then use it? Because you cannot write in a file or read from it unless you open it. Hope this helped! :)

Comment: He is using a `using` statement which means that he doesn't have to manage opening and closing the stream